# REM size not being updated even though I set html font-size

Tags: css, font-size

I have set the html and body to `15px`.

[image]

And afterwards I have set some padding of an element to `1rem`, which should translate to `15px`. But instead it's giving me `16px`...

[image]

Any idea why?

--

Browser: Google Chrome. MacOS.
CSS: Stylus
Framework: Vue.js + NUXT

Comment: Is your stylesheet definitely loading?

Comment: Yeah. These screenshots are from the inspector. They're not being overwritten.

Comment: What element is showing that padding?

Comment: @sol It's padding from a button element.

Comment: When you define 1rem, it should give you 1rem and not 15 or 16 pixels. Looks like the 16 pixels are defined somewhere else.

Comment: I just wrote "padding 1rem;" it's the middle line of the screenshot you see. The rest are computed styles.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/8o7pj979/) reports 15px for the padding. Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Also, which browser and which OS are you using? What dpi density does your screen have, are you zoomed in or out etc.

Comment: @mesqueeb this could happen if you have set / defined a minimum font size in your browser settings e.g. https://ibb.co/gqRZqo

Comment: @Danield Thank you very much. Safari doesn't have that setting enabled. Also, Google chrome has the default set to 16px. But this is just what should be overwritten with `html { font-size: 15px }` I thought...

I updated the question with more info about my browser. Unfortunately I cannot recreate the problem in a codepen....... I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to also set the following:

```
:root {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: No. `html` is exactly the same as `:root` in a HTML document. There is no difference. Or, there shouldn't be. If you can detect a difference in your situation, please tell us what the situation is exactly!

Comment: @MrLister
I updated the question with more info about my browser. Unfortunately I cannot recreate the problem in a codepen....... I'm not sure why.

Comment: @MrLister there is a difference in specificity. Root has higher priority over html tag according to W3 specs. I’m on mobile but I’ll get the link soon

Comment: @Mr Lister: soulshined is right. They may match the same element in an HTML document, but they still have different specificity. Another author-level stylesheet may be setting the font size using the :root selector. (If I'm honest, I don't know when tutorials began using :root in place of html outside of IE9 hacks to reference the root element, but it's now become a point of confusion for many authors.)

Comment: @soulshined and BoltClock I stand corrected. That doesn't explain why the OP would get different results with `:root` than with `html` though, unless there is more CSS to it. Which is probably the case, and the reason why it's difficult to get the codepen to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I agree @MrLister maybe third party library, or maybe even a hidden `!important` we don’t know about. Although this answer isn’t wrong, it’s kind of misleading to future question seekers. When in doubt :root it out is the lesson learned I suppose :/

Comment: The OP should be able to look in the inspector and see what is applying the font size of 16px.  It should tell him where it is coming from.  Somewhere in the list of styles there has to be a 16px.